# Best practice for polling an AWS SQS queue and deleting received messages from queue?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue that is constantly being populated by a data consumer and I am now trying to create the service that will pull this data from SQS using Python's boto.

The way I designed it is that I will have 10-20 threads all trying to read messages from the SQS queue and then doing what they have to do on the data (business logic), before going back to the queue to get the next batch of data once they're done. If there's no data they will just wait until some data is available.

I have two areas I'm not sure about with this design

1. Is it a matter of calling receive_message() with a long time_out value and if nothing is returned in the 20 seconds (maximum allowed) then just retry? Or is there a blocking method that returns only once data is available?
2. I noticed that once I receive a message, it is not deleted from the queue, do I have to receive a message and then send another request after receiving it to delete it from the queue? seems like a little bit of an overkill.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The long-polling capability of the `receive_message()` method is the most efficient way to poll SQS.  If that returns without any messages, I would recommend a short delay before retrying, especially if you have multiple readers.  You may want to even do an incremental delay so that each subsequent empty read waits a bit longer, just so you don't end up getting throttled by AWS.

And yes, you do have to delete the message after you have read or it will reappear in the queue.  This can actually be very useful in the case of a worker reading a message and then failing before it can fully process the message.  In that case, it would be re-queued and read by another worker.  You also want to make sure the invisibility timeout of the messages is set to be long enough the the worker has enough time to process the message before it automatically reappears on the queue.  If necessary, your workers can adjust the timeout as they are processing if it is taking longer than expected.

Answer (score 11):

If you want a simple way to set up a listener that includes automatic deletion of messages when they're finished being processed, and automatic pushing of exceptions to a specified queue, you can use the [pySqsListener](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pySqsListener/) package.

You can set up a listener like this:

```
from sqs_listener import SqsListener

class MyListener(SqsListener):
    def handle_message(self, body, attributes, messages_attributes):
        run_my_function(body['param1'], body['param2']

listener = MyListener('my-message-queue', 'my-error-queue')
listener.listen()
```

There is a flag to switch from short polling to long polling - it's all documented in the README file.

Disclaimer: I am the author of said package.

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to setup a worker application using AWS Beanstalk as described in [this blogpost](https://medium.com/aws-activate-startup-blog/a-sample-app-for-startups-2f8483c62b68#.45fxb1881).

Instead of long polling using boto3, your flask application receives the message as a json object in a HTTP post. The HTTP path and type of message being set are configurable in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Configuration tab:

[image]

AWS Elastic Beanstalk has the added benefit of being able to dynamically scale the number of workers as a function of the size of your SQS queue, along with its deployment management benefits.

[This](http://github.com/awslabs/eb-py-flask-signup-worker/blob/master/application.py) is an example application that I found useful as a template.